# How to use PageControl to view different UITableViews?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipagecontrol

I would like to know if I could add a UIPageControl to a TableViewController in order to flip sideways between different tables?

What is the right way to go about this?

Is there some sample code to implement this? The code on the Apple website looks complicated for a beginner like me, does not use Storyboards and it only deals with some images.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe you look at `UICollectionView` if you can do it with iOS6 and later. It is basically a `UIScrollView` where you can enable paging. Then for each of the elements, just add a `UITableView` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using TableViewController, I would just use ViewController implementing UITableView data source and delegate.

Place UITableView and UIPageControl in that and then on change in UIPageControl, change the data source of the tableview and use UITableView.reloadSections with appropriate UITableViewRowAnimation (Right or Left).

You can also add gesture recognizers on the tableview to allow swipe left/right.